# Взаимодействие VBA с уже загруженными расширениями (Add-In) в Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Имеется ли возможность с помощью VBA взаимодействовать с уже с загруженными расширениями в Excel?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под взаимодействием? *загруженные расширения* - это как? Уточните вопрос

Comment: Могу ли я автоматизировать действия, которые необходимо совершить через расширение, которое уже работает в Excel?

Comment: Вы повторили то же самое, непонятное, но другими словами. Дополните вопрос, опишите, что нужно, покажите пример